# Find the equation of the line passing through the 2 points of the tangents on a circle from point $(x_1,y_1)$

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line

Given a circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and a point P(x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>) outside of the circle. I can draw two tangents from P to the circle. I will call A and B the points where the tangents cross the circle. How can I show that the line that passes through A and B is defined by $x.x_1+y.y_1=r^2$?

The slope of the line is $-x_1/y_1$ because that line is perpendicular to the line that goes from (0,0) to (x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>).

How can I show that the intercept is $r^2/y_1$?

Comment: Instead of calculating the intercept, calculate the distance from O to the line AB.

Comment: If I call that point C, I get that the distance OC is $r^2/\sqrt(x_1^2+y_1^2)$

Comment: How can I use that to prove that $x.x_1+y.y_1=r^2$?

Comment: Recall the normal form of equation of a straight line.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Suppose that we know how to find the equation of the tangent at a point on the circle.

Here is another approach to show that $x_1 x + y_1 y=r^2 $ is the equation of $AB$.

Note that the equation of the tangent at $A(\alpha, \beta)$ is:
$$x \alpha + y \beta=r^2$$
Similarly the equation of the tangent at $B(\gamma, \delta)$ is:
$$x \gamma + y \delta = r^2$$

Since $P(x_1, y_1)$ lies on both tangents, therefore

$$x_1 \alpha + y_1 \beta=r^2   \tag{1}$$  and  $$x_1 \gamma + y_1 \delta = r^2    \tag{2}$$

Now consider the straight line equation $$x_1 x + y_1 y=r^2   \tag{*}$$

Notice that $A(\alpha, \beta)$ satisfies $(*)$ because of $(1)$.

Similarly $B(\gamma, \delta)$ satisfies $(*)$ because of $(2)$.

Hence $$x_1 x + y_1 y=r^2 $$ is the equation of the straight line passing through $A$ and $B$.